# Find and Replace a data column with array of values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find and replace data in column F2:F with the values stated in the array. But the fact is that I am missing something here, since nothing happen when the code is executed.

```
function cleanbbimport() {
  const rangeToModify = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('BDD!F2:F');
  const replaceWith = [
    ['611720', '446'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600690', '148c'],
    ['600190', '162c'],
    ['601260', '232c'],
    ['601480', '292c'],
    ['600620', '331c'],
    ['600960', '372c'],
    ['600440', '408c'],
    ['601160', '419c'],
    ['611630', '428c'],
    ['601110', '441c'],
    ['601130', '502c'],
    ['601510', '521c'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600810', '599c'],
    ['600320', '624c'],
    ['601720', '633c'],
    ['602270', '678c'],
    ['600870', '711c'],
  ];
  let values = rangeToModify.getDisplayValues();
  replaceWith.forEach(tuple =>
    values = values.map(row => row.map(value =>
      value.replace(tuple[0], tuple[1])
    ))
  );
  rangeToModify.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: What's is F?...

Comment: I mean the range F2:F

Comment: Ok what's in F2:F

Comment: The code you quote seems fine. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put column rep[0] in column F

```
function cleanbbimport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("F2:F" + sh.getLastRow());
  const rep = [
    ['611720', '446'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600690', '148c'],
    ['600190', '162c'],
    ['601260', '232c'],
    ['601480', '292c'],
    ['600620', '331c'],
    ['600960', '372c'],
    ['600440', '408c'],
    ['601160', '419c'],
    ['611630', '428c'],
    ['601110', '441c'],
    ['601130', '502c'],
    ['601510', '521c'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600810', '599c'],
    ['600320', '624c'],
    ['601720', '633c'],
    ['602270', '678c'],
    ['600870', '711c'],
  ];
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  let fA = rep.map(r => r[0]);
  let rA = rep.map(r => r[1]);
  vs.map((r,j) => {
    fA.forEach((e,i) => {
      let idx = r[0].toString().indexOf(e);
      if(~idx) {
        vs[i][0] = vs[i][0].replace(e,rA[i])
      }
    })
  })
  rg.setValues(vs);
}
```

Sheet0 Before:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 611720 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 601420 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 600690 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 600190 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 601260 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 601480 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 600620 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 600960 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 600440 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 601160 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 611630 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 601110 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 601130 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 601510 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 601420 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 600810 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 600320 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 601720 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 602270 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 600870 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |

Sheet0 After:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 446 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 540c | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 148c | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 162c | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 232c | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 292c | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 331c | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 372c | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 408c | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 419c | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 428c | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 441c | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 502c | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 521c | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 540c | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 599c | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 624c | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 633c | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 678c | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 711c | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |

Answer to additional question:

```
function answertoquestion() {
  function cleanbbimport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("F2:G" + sh.getLastRow());
  const rep = [
    ['611720', '446'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600690', '148c'],
    ['600190', '162c'],
    ['601260', '232c'],
    ['601480', '292c'],
    ['600620', '331c'],
    ['600960', '372c'],
    ['600440', '408c'],
    ['601160', '419c'],
    ['611630', '428c'],
    ['601110', '441c'],
    ['601130', '502c'],
    ['601510', '521c'],
    ['601420', '540c'],
    ['600810', '599c'],
    ['600320', '624c'],
    ['601720', '633c'],
    ['602270', '678c'],
    ['600870', '711c'],
  ];
  let vs = rg.getValues();
  let fA = rep.map(r => r[0]);
  let rA = rep.map(r => r[1]);
  vs.map((r,j) => {
    fA.forEach((e,i) => {
      let idx = r[0].toString().indexOf(e);
      if(~idx) {
        vs[i][0] = vs[i][0].replace(e,rA[i]);
        vs[i][1] = vs[i][1].replace(e,rA[i]);
      }
    })
  })
  rg.setValues(vs);
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite know what to put into column F but I figured anything that worked woudld be more helpful than nothing.  So I'm glad to hear that it helped.

Comment: Last question: If I want to apply the same find and replace to another column, can I replace this line: {const rg = sh.getRange("F2:F" + sh.getLastRow());}
by this one: {var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var rg = ['F2:F' + lastRow, 'G2:G' + lastRow];}
?
I'm getting this error [TypeError: rg.getValues is not a function]